# How can I run VLC command from c#

Tags: c#, vlc, transcoding, libvlcsharp

I'd like to know if there's a way to use vlc arguments from C# program using VlcSharp(any other API for vlc libraries will be acceptable as well).
I need to change codec of a video, that's why I have to do something like this: `--no-repeat --no-loop -vv "D:\688497.flv"--sout='#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mpga,vb=800,ab=128,deinterlace}:standard{access=file,mux=ts,dst="D:\asd.mpg"}'`(I have found this example [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/Transcode/)). 
As far as I know, one can add arguments in LibVLCSharp.Shared.Media construcor like this:

```
            libVLC = new LibVLC();
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(libVLC);
            using (var media = new LibVLCSharp.Shared.Media(libVLC, new Uri(CameraViewModel.RtspAddress),
                ":sout=#file{dst=" + destination + "}",
                ":sout-keep"))
            {
                this.mediaPlayer.Play(media);
            }
```

But when I'm adding argumetns from the prompt above nothing happens(at least the destination file, which has to be the output of the transcoding isn't created), so I am looking for a way to run a vlc command from c# app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You can give CLI arguments to LibVLC through the `LibVLC` constructor, or as a `Media` option. Example:

```cs
new LibVLC("--verbose=2");
```

See documentation here https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/blob/3.x/docs/how_do_I_do_X.md#how-do-i-use-libvlcs-advanced-options